# What's the practical difference between these two jQuery methods

Tags: jquery

Inherited old code I am trying to figure out.

Code loads an old version (c. 2012) of the Nivo slider, and initializes it thus:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nevoSlider();
});
```

Can I not just do this:

```
$('#slider').nevoSlider();
```

What does `$(window).load()` add to the equation?

Comment: it waits till the window... loads... which typically means after all images are done loading.

Comment: Just read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .load() event handler triggers once whatever it is bound to is done loading as well as all the sub elements of that selector. In this case whatever code nevoSlider() executes is called when the window finishes loading, include all the images.

Since Nivo Slider is a plugin designed specifically for images you probably want to leave the code within a $(window).load() binding. If you removed that portion, or even transferred it to a $(document).ready() binding, you could very likely experience some broken images in the image slider because the images haven't fully rendered.

Read up on the docs for .load() to get a better understanding but this seems to be the short and skinny of it. http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ - yarl already posted but here it is again.

Comment: Thank you -- you read my mind. Putting it inside a document.ready binding was exactly what I was intending to do. Very helpful and clear explanation, thanks.

Comment: Hang on, though... isn't that basically what document.ready does as well?  How can the document.ready fire if pieces (ie. images) haven't finished loading? *What is the difference between document.ready and $(window).load() ?*

Comment: $(document).ready() waits for all the HTML and DOM object to be available and accessible while $(window).load() waits for everything to be available on the page, not just the DOM object. The biggest difference here is WHEN these fire and $(window).load() is a little later once all external assets have loaded as well, in this case namely images. It is a small difference but an important one. http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: Exactly what I need to know. Thanks Jason.